# Logging of JasperExceptions suppressed by presence of errorPage

Tags: java, jsp

In my JSP pages, I start with a designation of an errorPage, in order to show a standard message to users (though I don't show users the JSP errors).

```
<%@ page errorPage="myErrorPage.jsp" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

However, when I include this page directive, it causes JasperExceptions to no longer be written to my app logs.  I need to see the JasperException in my app logs so I can find errors in my JSP.

Is there a way to designate an errorPage and still tell Jasper to continue to log JasperExceptions in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a way to do this.  The designated error handling page needs to re-throw the JSP-related exception.
e.g.: myErrorPage.jsp would be:

```
<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
<html>
<head>
    <%-- 
    *************************************************************************
      To be used for displaying jsp error .
      On every jsp page insert the directive below:
      <%@page errorPage="errorsnaps.jsp" buffer="64kb" %>   
      Note: page buffer attribute shown above is also a good idea. 
      Otherwise, if default 8k buffer overflows,
      the original page will start to be output BEFORE a jsp error is encountered,
      which causes this page to come out after a partial erroneous page, creating a big mess!
      TODO: Could just have an errorPage designation in web.xml -- that makes sure to get all pages.
   *************************************************************************    
    --%>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        A generic user-friendly message that does not disclose the actual error.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<%
if ( exception != null ) 
{
    out.flush();
    throw (exception);
}
%>
```